# Get last n items in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For a dataset like -

```
+---+------+----------+
| id|  item| timestamp|
+---+------+----------+
|  1| apple|2022-08-15|
|  1| peach|2022-08-15|
|  1| apple|2022-08-15|
|  1|banana|2022-08-14|
|  2| apple|2022-08-15|
|  2|banana|2022-08-14|
|  2|banana|2022-08-14|
|  2| water|2022-08-14|
|  3| water|2022-08-15|
|  3| water|2022-08-14|
+---+------+----------+
```

Can I use pyspark functions directly to get last three items the user purchased in the past 5 days? I know udf can do that, but I am wondering if any existing funtion can achieve this.

My expected output is like below or anything simliar is okay too.

```
id        last_three_item
1   [apple, peach, apple]
2  [water, banana, apple]
3          [water, water]
```

Thanks!

Comment: see `collect_list()` / `collect_set()` functions. they can also be used as window functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pandas_udf** for this.

```
@f.pandas_udf(returnType=ArrayType(StringType()), functionType=f.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def pudf_get_top_3(x):
    return x.head(3).to_list()

sdf\
   .orderby("timestamp")\
   .groupby("id")\
   .agg(pudf_get_top_3("item")\
        .alias("last_three_item))\
   .show()
```